# How to get TextView reference in a FragmentActivity from inside a OnClickListener on a button in the same activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity, textview, listener

Let me explain, I had this `Activity`, where there is a `Button` and a `TextView`. I had to create a listener to this button(can't be a inner class or private class), lets call `ButtonListener`. I need to change the `TextView` from the `Activity` inside the `ButtonListener`. How do I do that?

Activity --> `Button b, TextView t`

```
b.setOnClickListener(ButtonListener listener)
```

listener --> `onClick()` { //need to change the TextView here }

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

ImageView    button     = null;
TextView     text       = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayoutxml);

    text       = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.id_TextView);
    button     = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.id_ImageView);


    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                    //here you can manage your TextView     
                    text.doSomething();
            }
      }                         );
}
}
```

Hope this help.